# ASM/NASM - Return high low of a MUL in a type struct

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention, int128

```
global mymul
mymul:
    mov rax, rdi
    mul rsi
    ret
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
        unsigned long long high;
            unsigned long long low;
} resmul;

void mymul(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, resmul *res);

int main() {
    resmul res;

    mymul(3, 6, &res);
    printf("mymul(3, 6); res.high=0x%llx, res.low=0x%llx\n", res.high, res.low);
    //mymul(3, 6); res.high=0x0, res.low=0x12
    return 0;
}
```

the goal is to multiply first arg with the second and send to result to the last arg
first arg = RDI / second arg = RSI
goal to send result high/low to typestruct

I dont understand why it gives 0 to both results
RAX and RDX should be returned but i doesnt

Answer (score 2):

Your `mymul` function is declared from C as taking a pointer argument, where it should be storing the results in memory.  But in fact it is leaving them in the rdx:rax registers and never storing anything in memory at all, ignoring the pointer completely.

The third argument would be passed in the rdx register, which complicates things a little because `mul` overwrites it.  So you have to do something like

```
global mymul
mymul:
    mov rcx, rdx  ; save argument
    mov rax, rdi
    mul rsi
    mov [rcx], rdx
    mov [rcx+8], rax
    ret
```

Comment: Oh thanks! But why do we add + and not 8, shouldnt we add  4 bytes ?

Comment: @1111B: `unsigned long long` is 64 bits which is 8 bytes.  Your `mymul` function is multiplying two 64-bit inputs to produce a 128-bit output.

Comment: IMO, the right fix is to change the prototype and caller, not make everything less efficient by returning by reference.  (And to leave the struct backwards, with the high element at the lower address.)

Answer (score 0):

You told the compiler your function returns `void`, so the caller isn't looking at RDX:RAX.

Use a debugger and/or look at the asm in the caller; it will be loading its uninitialized local variable `res` from the stack, and that unwritten stack memory just happens to be zero.

---

To properly declare a function returning in RDX:RAX for the x86-64 SysV calling convention, either ****return a struct**, or return `unsigned __int128` if you're using GNU extensions.**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
        uint64_t low;         // low first, the low half of RDX:RAX
        uint64_t high;
} resmul;              // x86-64 System V will return this in RDX:RAX, like __int128

resmul mymul(uint64_t, uint64_t);  // your function doesn't look for a pointer in RDX

int main() {
    resmul res = mymul(3, 6);
    printf("mymul(3, 6); res.high=%#lx, res.low=%#lx\n", res.high, res.low);
    //mymul(3, 6); res.high=0x0, res.low=0x12
    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:6,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:6,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:6,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:6,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Atypedef+struct+%7B%0A++++++++uint64_t+low%3B+++++++++//+low+first,+the+low+half+of+RDX:RAX%0A++++++++uint64_t+high%3B%0A%7D+resmul%3B++++++++++++++//+x86-64+System+V+will+return+this+in+RDX:RAX,+like+__int128%0A%0Aresmul+mymul(uint64_t,+uint64_t)%3B++//+your+function+doesn!%27t+look+for+a+pointer+in+RDX%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++resmul+res+%3D+mymul(3,+6)%3B%0A++++printf(%22mymul(3,+6)%3B+res.high%3D%25%23lx,+res.low%3D%25%23lx%5Cn%22,+res.high,+res.low)%3B%0A++++//mymul(3,+6)%3B+res.high%3D0x0,+res.low%3D0x12%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23if+0%0A//+compiles+to+the+same+asm%0Aresmul+mymul(uint64_t+a,+uint64_t+b)%7B%0A++++unsigned+__int128+prod+%3D+a+*+(unsigned+__int128)b%3B%0A++++return+(resmul)%7Bprod,+prod%3E%3E64%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0A%0Aunsigned+__int128+mulv2(uint64_t+a,+uint64_t+b)%7B%0A++++return+a+*+(unsigned+__int128)b%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:35.99514583278259,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:30.671520833884088,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), also including GNU C implementations of your function that compile to the same asm:

```c
// compiles to the same asm
resmul mymul(uint64_t a, uint64_t b){
    unsigned __int128 prod = a * (unsigned __int128)b;
    return (resmul){prod, prod>>64};
}

unsigned __int128 mulv2(uint64_t a, uint64_t b){
    return a * (unsigned __int128)b;
}
```

```
mymul(unsigned long, unsigned long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        mul     rsi
        ret
mulv2(unsigned long, unsigned long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        mul     rsi
        ret
```